# possible to segue with xib gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to go to a different segue if the user clicks on an element like imageview from the xib (via gesture recognizer) instead of the rest of the row in a tableView (since that is a different segue). I have seen people do it with objective C, but I am not sure how to do it in Swift, has anyone done it before successfully? I know I would have to make the code changes on the custom xib file and then get the actual controller to make the transition (if I am to go by the objective C way).

Comment: what kind is your custom xib? TableCell?

Comment: yes it is a tableCell xib

Comment: while it can be achieved using gesturerecognizer on imageview, i would suggest using a uibutton on top of imageview. UIButton is more optimized for touches and is easy to implement. Does your situation allows using UIButton? If yes, i can write a detailed answer on how to implement it

Comment: I could replace the label to be a button and make it look like a label so its totally doable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have a UIButton in your cell, you can use the below code to performSegue on its click.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : YourCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCell
    cell.imageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(imageTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}


@objc func imageTapped(sender : UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifer", sender: self)
}
```

So in cellForRowAt, we are assigning your imageButton a function that will be called whenever the button is clicked i.e. imageTapped()

As your imageTapped function is in your viewController, you can easily perform a segue by creating one from VC1 to VC2

Comment: Thanks! I put a translucent button on top of an imageView and then set the target for that xib element and it works like a charm!